# Is it possible to remove and readd React eventListener within the handler function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, removeeventlistener

I am working with something like fullpage.js with React, and I need to remove the eventListener while the transition is ongoing.

Is it possible?

React code

```
function App() {
  const wheelHandler = (event) => {
     // I need to remove wheelHandler here

     setTimeout(() => {
       // I need to readd wheelHandler here
     }, 1000); // Assume that the transition ends after 1000ms
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onWheel={wheelHandler} />
  );
}
```

Vanilla JS equivalent

```
const wheelHandler = (event) => {
  window.removeEventListener(wheelHandler);

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.addEventListener(wheelHandler);
  }, 1000);
};

window.addEventListener(wheelHandler);
```

P.S. I tried the Vanilla JS solution on React but the event handler got triggered multiple times on one wheel scroll. Therefore I got no choice but React's SyntheticEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you're hooking it up, you can't without using a piece of state that tells you whether to hook up the handler and re-rendering, which is probably overkill.

Instead, I'd set a flag (perhaps on an object via a ref) telling the handler to ignore calls during the time you want calls ignored.

Something long these lines:

```
function App() {
  const {current: scrolling} = useRef({flag: false});
  const wheelHandler = (event) => {
     // I need to remove wheelHandler here
     if (scrolling.flag) {
         // Bail out
         return;
     }
     scrolling.flag = true;

     // ...other logic if any...

     setTimeout(() => {
       // I need to readd wheelHandler here
       scrolling.flag = false;
     }, 1000); // Assume that the transition ends after 1000ms
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onWheel={wheelHandler} />
  );
}
```

Or you can also do it like this, you don't need an extra object (I tend to prefer to use a single ref that holds all of my non-state instance data, but you don't have to):

```
function App() {
  const scrolling = useRef(false);
  const wheelHandler = (event) => {
     // I need to remove wheelHandler here
     if (scrolling.current) {
         // Bail out
         return;
     }
     scrolling.current = true;

     // ...other logic if any...

     setTimeout(() => {
       // I need to readd wheelHandler here
       scrolling.current = false;
     }, 1000); // Assume that the transition ends after 1000ms
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onWheel={wheelHandler} />
  );
}
```

As they say in [the `useRef` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), refs are useful for non-state instance information:

> However, `useRef()` is useful for more than the `ref` attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.

Comment: Thanks it works.A few questions though, How does `scrolling` different from normal variables? Why It doesn't work if I use it like `useRef(false)` and `scrolling= false;`?

Comment: I mean `let { current: scrolling } = React.useRef(false);
` and `scrolling = false;`

Comment: @Max - Good question! That doesn't work because React doesn't know you've done it. `useRef` gives you a ref object with a `current` property, and it always gives you back the same ref object. You can do whatever you want with the `current` property. In my original example, I was setting `current` to an object with a `flag` property and then changing that `flag` property. Since React always gives you back the same ref object, that change to the property persists between calls. But if you just grab the `current` property to a local variable and change the local variable, that doesn't change...

Comment: ...the `current` property, just the local variable. But my example can be simpler, I've added a second version of it. I wrote it the way I did originally out of habit, I tend to use a single ref (when I need one at all) to hold all of my non-state instance information, so I used an object with properties (`flag`). But you can also just change the value of `current` directly. See the second example for ... er ... an example. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is clear. I understand it now :)